# Implicit plot3d in Sage Math

Tags: multivariable-calculus, math-software, sagemath

I am currently trying out using the math software Sage. I am currently in a Calculus III class at my university so I was hoping to be able to leverage its 3D graphing capabilities. In one particular problem I have:

> Evaluate the triple integral: f(x,y,z) = $1/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{1/2}$ over the bottom half of the sphere of radius 5 centered at the origin.

To get a good feel for the region I am supposed to integrate over, I wanted to see if I could plot the function in Sage. Below is my syntax:

> x,y,z = var('x,y,z')
>
> > f(x,y,z) = 1/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) ^(1/2)
> >
> > > implicit_plot3d(f,(x,-0.5,0.5), (y,-0.5,0.5), (z,-0.5,0.5))

The syntax runs as shown, but when the graph pops up I get nothing. Would someone be able to help troubleshoot me? Is the function too complex for Sage? Is my syntax wrong? Is there another way I could approach plotting the region?

Thank you very much in advance for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: I just want to mention that I replicated SAGE's mysterious reaction to this command myself. I have used SAGE for a while, and it seems like your syntax is right. I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: When you replicated it, did you get the same result? Or did you actually get the graph?

Comment: Same result. Also I was running an install on my home server. Were you on SageMathCloud when you tried it?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the SageMathCloud, but I was running it from a Virtual Machine on my laptop if that's what you were referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's think about what you are plotting.  Implicit plotting will plot *exactly* what you ask it to.  But this is a function of three variables, so its graph would live in four dimensions... So when that function $f(x,y,z)$ is implicitly plotted, there must be a "level surface" being plotted, not the whole graph.  The level surface you have chosen is for $f(x,y,z)=0$.  Think about when this expression equals zero (which is what Sage will default to if you don't ask it for more).  Note that you should get a graph viewer, just not the graph itself, right?

PS: You may have to change the bounds of the plot too, if you try the right thing; you have pretty small bounds in this case.

PPS: If it weren't for the math error, it really isn't a math.sx question, but one for [ask.sagemath](http://ask.sagemath.org/questions/) or [SO.com](https://stackoverflow.com/) itself, since it's not a math question per se.  Anyway, good luck!

---

Edit: persistence pays off.

```
f(x,y,z) = 1/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) ^(1/2)
implicit_plot3d(f==1,(x,-1,1), (y,-1,1), (z,-1,1))
```

See also [this live version](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?q=qyhejx).  Also note you don't have to explicitly declare these variables because you declare them with `f(x,y,z) = ...`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! So is my problem setting $f(x,y,z)$ to a level surface other than $0$?

Comment: There is no problem!  Just try some other level surface which is nonempty and fits inside your bounds; it should work fine.

Comment: Do you think you could give a syntax example? I apologize, I'm new to this and wanted to make sure I was understanding. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Okay, though I was hoping to encourage you to start trying things for yourself - it's only with the struggle that we really internalize things.  Anyway, hope this helps, and good luck!